# How to extend InfiniteContainer with the capability of expanding the nodes in the Tree class?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to have an InfiniteContainer that also behaves like a Tree so I can expand the nodes. What is the best approach to do this?

I guess I can extend InfiniteContainer to MyInfiniteContainer and manually copy over all the code from Tree, but I am hoping there is a less cumbersome approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibility I can think of with 3 different answers:

1. This is a VERY long list where some of the elements can be expanded.
2. This is a very deep [Tree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html)
3. This is a a very long list and a very deep tree for ALL entries

For option 1 I would just use a [Tree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html) component occasionally within the standard buttons or whatever you have in the [InfiniteContainer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html). Make sure to invoke `setScrollable(false)` on the [Tree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html) elements to prevent nested scrolling.

For option 2 I would just go with a [Tree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html) directly and ignore the [InfiniteContainer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html). You can implement the `TreeModel` yourself which is invoked lazily.

I'd try the same solution for 1 when going for option 3 but if it doesn't scale you can just look at the Tree source code and try to implement something similar.

Comment: (Hit Enter to early) Thanks! It's a very long list where some of the elements can be potentially deep trees. The elements at all levels are the same (recursively expanded). However, most likely only a few will be expanded at any one time, so 1. is probably fine. I wanted anyway to replace the Tree buttons with more elaborate components (with multiple buttons for different actions like expandTree, editElement). So, if I understand you correctly, I can simply add a Tree model inside the InfiniteContainer components and use the same elaborate component in both the InfiniteContainer and the Tree.

Comment: You can add a Tree (as long as you make it non-scrollable) into the  InfiniteContainer. You can override the trees component creation logic so it has complex buttons within it.